# Save only 10 Records but delete all others by ID Huge Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-delete

I need a solution to remove all records but save last 10 by ID_URL not BY UNIQUE ID (primary Key)..

MY Database Structure and Records View..

I need to save last 10 ITEM of EVERY URL_ID..

EDIT: Maybe most or are you confused what I am asking about.. actually I just want to save NEW 10 EVERY URL_ID records only..

```
   ID   IP             TIME(TIMESTAMP)   BROWSER                                                Visitor_URL     URL_ID
   11   xxx.xxx.xx.xx   3/15/2010 14:43 Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.2.15 V...   link_link          TYTIP
   12   xxx.xxx.xx.xx   3/15/2010 14:43 Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.2.15 V...   link_link          TITPE
   13   xxx.xxx.xx.xx   3/15/2010 14:43 Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.2.15 V...   link_link          XAIP
   14   xxx.xxx.xx.xx   3/15/2010 14:44 Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.2.15 V...   link_link          TYTIP
   15   xxx.xxx.xx.xx   3/15/2010 14:44 Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.2.15 V...   link_link          TYTIP
   .....1000's of Other Records
```

Comment: So, given your sample data, and you wanted to keep only the newest `2` of each type, you'd want ID's 12, 13, 14, 15 preserved. but not 11 because it's the 3rd oldest of `TYTIP`?

Comment: @MarcB Yes.. i don't need more then 10 recrods of each URL ID..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you make a predefined list of `url_id`?

Because then you can do:

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE url_id = 'TITPE'
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 10,18446744073709551615;
```

This will delete in reverse order, skipping the first 10 rows (and since it's in reverse, those are the most recent rows).

PS. Be sure to test this before trying it on live data.

Comment: I need a solution to find URL_ID and SAVE last 10 records... do i need to use Select? or is there any possibility to remove with one single query?

Comment: limit gets slower as offset gets larger. This looks uber slow.

Comment: @Johan the offset is fixed at 10, the second number is the number of rows, which is just set to max.

Comment: @Johan its not a big problem.. i could use PHP loop to delte 1000 recrods in every loop.. every time i will use new database connection..

Comment: @Muhammad you don't need to do that. But in any case einsteinx2 method will be a LOT faster - but you will have to stop your application while it works, mine you can do live. So it's your choice which to choose.

Comment: i will accept both Answer, because Your **Answer** is use with every time  i add new records to database and **@einsteinx2** answer use for one time to remove extra records or use as cron job.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to save a very small subset of records and delete the rest, it's much more efficient (in every database engine I'm familiar with) to select those records you're keeping into a temp table, drop and re-create the original table, and then select the records back in.

So for instance something like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS records_temp;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE records_temp LIKE original_table;
INSERT INTO records_temp SELECT * FROM original_table WHERE URL_ID = "TYTIP" ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10;
(then do that again for each type)
DROP TABLE original_table;
CREATE TABLE original_table LIKE records_temp;
INSERT INTO original_table SELECT * FROM records_temp;
DROP TABLE records_temp;
```

Comment: its a good solution.. but still i need PHP loop to and URL_ID and remove data.. is there any solution i can do without php usage?

Comment: I thought quite this a bit but I can see no way to do that in one query. (Same for my delete version.) You can write a stored procedure to do this though, so you can do it in MySQL and not PHP.

Comment: @Ariel i am not too much fimiler with `mysql stored procedure`

Comment: Using a stored procedure is a good option, but has a learning curve (though I highly recommend learning them as they are very useful). You could use a php loop after selecting all URL_ID types, or if you know them already you can just hard code one query for each type. I don't think you can do it in one query, even using a subquery. If you absolutely need to use just one query for this, I would recommend then taking a day to learn basic stored procedure writing and implementing it that way. Then you run just one query `CALL sp_cleantable;` and it will run.